How to create dynamic JPA CriteriaQuery that supports partial select and joins
I need to use JPA CriteriaQuery to select custom columns making use of relations and joins.
My JPA entities:
...
@Entity
public class Application {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    private Revision revision;
  
    // Many more fields
}

...
@Entity
public class Revision {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private RevisionStatus status = RevisionStatus.DRAFT;

    // Many more fields
}

I want to query Applications and get back Applications but to have partial Application object.
The goal is to have a query like:
select a1_0.id,r1_0.status
from applications a1_0 join revisions r1_0 on r1_0.id=a1_0.revision_id

I will get back a List<Application> where only id and revision and revision.status are initialized.
The columns I want to select (e.g., "id", "revision.status") are passed as parameters to a generic method.
My method signature should look like:
public List<T> fetch(Class<T> clazz, String... fields);

and example usages can be:
List<Application> applications = fetch(Application.class, "id");

or:
applications = fetchApplications(Application.class, "id", "revision.id");

or:
applications = fetchApplications(Application.class, "id", "name", "revision.status");

As a first step, I am trying to write code that works and later I can convert to fully dynamic. Something like:
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Application> query = cb.createQuery(Application.class);
    Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);
    query.multiselect(root.get("id").alias("id"), root.get("revision").get("status").alias("revision.status"));

    List<Application> applications = entityManager.createQuery(query)
            .getResultList();

but this does not work because JPA/Hibernate does not understand that "revision.status" is nested field:
org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.InstantiationException: Cannot set field 'revision.status' to instantiate 'com.algosec.bflow.entities.Application'

One option is to use createTupleQuery but then I will need to convert the Tuple to T myself.
Thank you.
